# What to do about offensive language in seeds?

Tags: discussion

I'm not sure what action to take for [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/53578/3610). Normally I'd edit out foul language, but that's not possible here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's most likely just a troll. Even if that was a seed that worked there are better seeds that don't need to use these words.